# How to set sizes and srcset image attributes to max-width?

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image with width 50px and container that is 500px. Using code below will stretch image 100% width and the image size will be 500px even if I set `max-width: 100%`.

How can I set image to 50px, but if image size is more then 500px, it will be stretched to 500px as it's 100%? Note: I can not set `sizes` attribute to 50px, because firstly I don't know actual width, and secondly image must be 500px if it's more then 500px.

*Why I ask this question? I have a blog and upload images to website with `php`+`javascript`. Php script resizes images to 50px, 200px, 500px. But if image that I upload is less than 500px (for example, 300px), `srcset` will contain only `image_50.jpg 50w, image_200.jpg 200w`.*

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
  <img src="image_50.jpg" sizes="100vw" srcset="image_50.jpg 50w" style="max-width:100%;">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/baL5cj0k/4/

**p.s. I am wondering why it is so complicated for such a common situation with small images**

Comment: to be clear you want the image to span the whole div but dont want it to go below 50px?

Comment: No, man.. I want image to stay 50px always. The code above makes it 100% = 500px

Comment: Why the down vote you just said you need image to stay 50 px no matter what.  don't matter img size with my answer it will be scaled to fit

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do that exclusively with html and css, you will need JavaScript or server-side scripting for that.

Comment: max-width: 100% Is relative to the container, not the object itself. That means that max-width: 100% in a container that is 500px will always return 500px. You should do this on php side, when you request the blog post, search for 500px image, if not, get 50px image.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this by using srcset inside picture tag.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcset="image_500.jpg">
  <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="image_50.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are giving 50w in srcset. if you increase the value of that count then your image will be fine. not sure what is working on backside.

```html
<div style="width: 500px; background: pink; padding: 10px;">
  <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c638627/v638627399/5e1c7/UytL9PuXiq8.jpg" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://pp.userapi.com/c638627/v638627399/5e1c7/UytL9PuXiq8.jpg 500w" style="max-width:100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice trick, it works! But I don't understand how. Why picture is 50px width if we set 500w? Moreover, we cheat browsers: they treat 500w that this picture is 500px width, but this is not true.

Comment: Yes I also didn't know what is happpen on backend

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
<div style="width: 500px; background: pink; padding: 10px;">
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-XGHxN3OtzOs/UXVmomnjriI/AAAAAAAAAh8/A0PKMFP8XcE/s1600/browser0.png" style="max-width:100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set `sizes:100vw` with `50w` which will stretch image to the parent width, thats why your image is bigger than actual size. Also you have mentioned you can't change the `sizes` attribute, So the best solution is here to remove the `w` descriptor

> *Note: If no descriptor is specified, the source is assigned the default descriptor: `1x`.*

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px;border:1px solid red;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" style="max-width:100%;">
  <br>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" style="max-width:100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But how do we make sets if we remove `w` descriptor? I mean you have only 1 image in `srcset` attribute. I need 4 images like `srcset="img_50.jpg 50w, img_300.jpg 300w, ..."`